# Google Maps Javascript API V3 not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this on the  of my .php file

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
    var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress(address) {  
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and along the page I have the div in a modal

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

But the map does not show in the modal... I get no errors on Opera Console and when I try to call the functions [initialize() and or codeAddress("Spain")] through the console it says undifined

I've created a page only for the map for testing and it worked fine.
Any ideas?
==EDIT==
After adding the height to my css file the map is shown with some problems 
http://postimg.org/image/mhj9awdez/
Only after a second initialization the map is shown correctly (the initialization must be done with the modal open)

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/Csk95/).

Comment: Map shows fine for me.

Comment: BTW, make sure you're adding width and height to your `map-canvas` element, either inline or using CSS.

Comment: You are lacking width/height as said earlier, here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GnFEY/)

Comment: I've added the height and the map is shown but I have this problem
http://postimg.org/image/mhj9awdez/

Comment: How do you call `codeAddress()`?

Comment: Using the opera console or in the page codeAddress("Coimbra, Portugal");

Answer (score 0):

you need to call initialize() function after the loading the js file ...
i think this will help you 
  <https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';>>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Asynchronous Loading</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working. When I call the codeAddress function it says on the console "Uncought TypeError: Cannot call method 'geocode' of undefined" and if I call initialize() it gives me "ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Comment: You can set the map into the iframe maybe you have anoder js file what is conflicted wth your map js .. I have simalar problem i solve it with iframe